# Were the black armor Stormtroopers supposed to be Dark Troopers from Legends?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, rogue-one

Throughout the film, we see a number of stormtroopers in black armor, most notably in the opening scene where Jyn's father is brought into service for the Empire. Unlike the Stormtroopers we see and hear later in the film, they don't seem to communicate with words, but rather some kind of muffled sounds in a tone that reminds me of the battle droids from the prequel trilogy.

Are these Dark Troopers from Legends continuity, which originated in the video game *[Star Wars: Dark Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Dark_Forces)*? These were droids that were designed as specialty Stormtroopers around the time of the Death Star.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are [Imperial Death Troopers](http://www.starwars.com/databank/imperial-death-troopers); the Databank describes them thusly:

> The elite soldiers of Imperial Intelligence, death troopers are encased in specialized stormtrooper armor with a dark, ominous gleam. These soldiers serve as bodyguards and enforcers for Director Krennic, a highly placed officer within the Advanced Weapons Research division of the Empire.

In contrast to the Dark Troopers of Legends, who were actually advanced battle droids<sup>1</sup>, Death Troopers are more akin to Stormtrooper special forces. Despite all appearances, they are fully organic.

### What's with the voice?

[On Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/816062597166342145), Pablo Hidalgo remarks that the Death Troopers aren't meant to be understood by non-Death Troopers:

[image]

> **@karlwiggins** Ok, I've seen it three times now and still don't know what they're saying...
>
> > **@karlwiggins** Do the Death Troopers speak a different language, are their comms encrypted, or was I too hard of hearing to understand?
>
> **@pablohidalgo** They're not meant to be understood by non-death troopers.

Which suggests that their comm chatter was encrypted.

---

<sup>1</sup> With some exceptions; the Mark III Dark Trooper could also function as an exoskeleton. I *really* hated that boss fight, incidentally.

Comment: Is there any information about their unusual way of speaking?

Comment: @Thunderforge Nothing satisfying, I'm afraid. Looked through the novelization and the Visual Guide, and didn't find a whole lot

Comment: @JasonBaker- I found the Mark III trooper fight easy- 'course I used the super shield option.